# How to pass argument to custom JSON deserializer in spring boot app

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to use my own deserializer in spring boot rest controller. To do its job, it needs some custom configuration - which is provided to it as constructor argument. How can I pass such argument in rest controller?

Here is example.

DTO(with some lombok annotations):

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)
public class DTO {
    private int a;
    private int b;
}
```

Deserializer:

```java
public class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DTO> {
    //custom config
    int val;

    public Deserializer(int value) {
        val = value;
    }

    @Override
    public DTO deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException{

        JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        int a = node.has("a") ? node.get("a").asInt() : -1;
        int b = node.has("b") ? node.get("b").asInt() : -1;
        //custom config usage
        return new DTO(a + val, b + val);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class Controller {
   //how to pass `val` into deserializer of DTO object?
    @PostMapping("/foo")
    DTO foo(@RequestBody DTO dto) {
        return dto;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom ObjectMapper and add your custom serializer to it and at the same time load in a custom value from application.properties.

I think this should work, wrote it from the top of my head.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Value("${customValue}")
    private int myCustomValue;

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

        module.addSerializer(new Deserializer(myCustomValue));
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what abot situation, when the val is not be static, i.e it will be passed to me as a part of payload?

Comment: Then you can’t have it in the constructor.

Comment: is there a way to pass spring request header to jsonDeserializer